# having issue in Removeall method of collection with POJO

Tags: java

**Java collection**

I have two Array list one is `lstreminder`, and other is `lstpresent`, there is code below for more specification:

```
lstintprsnt = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

lstreminder = DAORemider.getLatestReminder(u.getName());

if (lstpresent == null || lstpresent.isEmpty()) {

            lstpresent = lstreminder;
            System.out.println("i m in if" + lstpresent);
        } else {
            System.out.println("i m in else" + lstpresent.size());
            lstreminder.removeAll(lstpresent);

            /* at this position listreminder will be empty and do not execute loop, 
               but still it hold values and executed loo, but if  I try this with 
               an Integer arraylist then its work fine, means it not executed 
               loop, because it doesnt have any value */

            for (Reminder r : lstreminder) {
                System.out.println("lst" + r.getReminderid());
                lstpresent.add(r);
            }
            System.out.println("i m in else" + lstpresent);

        }
        System.out.println("out    " + lstpresent);
        ServletActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("lstpresent", lstpresent);
        lstpresent.clear();
```

Comment: What do you want to do? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assignment will just copy the value of lstreminder (which is a reference) to lstpresent . They will both refer to the same object.

Creating a copy is pretty easy though:

```
List lstpresent = new ArrayList(lstreminder );
```